# Runtime differences between two machines in TF.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I was working on a small scale project for Fashion MNIST. I have used the below code. I first tried executing the code on my primary machine and received an unchanging loss of ~2, after which I tried running the same code on my secondary machine and I could see that my loss and accuracy metrics were performing just the way they should have.
[image]

Here is my `index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-vis"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Fashion Classifier!</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="280" height="280" style="position:absolute;top:100;left:100;border:8px solid;"></canvas>
    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;width=280;height=280;display:none;">
    <input type="button" value="classify" id="sb" size="48" style="position:absolute;top:400;left:100;">
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="cb" size="23" style="position:absolute;top:400;left:180;">
    <script src="fashion-data.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="fashion-script_exercise.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A JS code to get the data

```
const IMAGE_SIZE = 784;
const NUM_CLASSES = 10;
const NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS = 70000;

const TRAIN_TEST_RATIO = 1 / 7;

const NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS = Math.floor(TRAIN_TEST_RATIO * NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS);
const NUM_TEST_ELEMENTS = NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS - NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS;

const MNIST_IMAGES_SPRITE_PATH =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/learnjs-data/model-builder/fashion_mnist_images.png';
const MNIST_LABELS_PATH =
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/learnjs-data/model-builder/fashion_mnist_labels_uint8';

export class FMnistData {
  constructor() {
    this.shuffledTrainIndex = 0;
    this.shuffledTestIndex = 0;
  }

  async load() {
    // Make a request for the MNIST sprited image.
    const img = new Image();
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const imgRequest = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      img.crossOrigin = '';
      img.onload = () => {
        img.width = img.naturalWidth;
        img.height = img.naturalHeight;

        const datasetBytesBuffer =
            new ArrayBuffer(NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS * IMAGE_SIZE * 4);

        const chunkSize = 5000;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = chunkSize;

        for (let i = 0; i < NUM_DATASET_ELEMENTS / chunkSize; i++) {
          const datasetBytesView = new Float32Array(
              datasetBytesBuffer, i * IMAGE_SIZE * chunkSize * 4,
              IMAGE_SIZE * chunkSize);
          ctx.drawImage(
              img, 0, i * chunkSize, img.width, chunkSize, 0, 0, img.width,
              chunkSize);

          const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          for (let j = 0; j < imageData.data.length / 4; j++) {
            // All channels hold an equal value since the image is grayscale, so
            // just read the red channel.
            datasetBytesView[j] = imageData.data[j * 4] / 255;
          }
        }
        this.datasetImages = new Float32Array(datasetBytesBuffer);

        resolve();
      };
      img.src = MNIST_IMAGES_SPRITE_PATH;
    });

    const labelsRequest = fetch(MNIST_LABELS_PATH);
    const [imgResponse, labelsResponse] =
        await Promise.all([imgRequest, labelsRequest]);

    this.datasetLabels = new Uint8Array(await labelsResponse.arrayBuffer());

    this.trainIndices = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testIndices = tf.util.createShuffledIndices(NUM_TEST_ELEMENTS);

    this.trainImages =
        this.datasetImages.slice(0, IMAGE_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testImages = this.datasetImages.slice(IMAGE_SIZE * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.trainLabels =
        this.datasetLabels.slice(0, NUM_CLASSES * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
    this.testLabels =
        this.datasetLabels.slice(NUM_CLASSES * NUM_TRAIN_ELEMENTS);
  }

  nextTrainBatch(batchSize) {
    return this.nextBatch(
        batchSize, [this.trainImages, this.trainLabels], () => {
          this.shuffledTrainIndex =
              (this.shuffledTrainIndex + 1) % this.trainIndices.length;
          return this.trainIndices[this.shuffledTrainIndex];
        });
  }

  nextTestBatch(batchSize) {
    return this.nextBatch(batchSize, [this.testImages, this.testLabels], () => {
      this.shuffledTestIndex =
          (this.shuffledTestIndex + 1) % this.testIndices.length;
      return this.testIndices[this.shuffledTestIndex];
    });
  }

  nextBatch(batchSize, data, index) {
    const batchImagesArray = new Float32Array(batchSize * IMAGE_SIZE);
    const batchLabelsArray = new Uint8Array(batchSize * NUM_CLASSES);

    for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
      const idx = index();

      const image =
          data[0].slice(idx * IMAGE_SIZE, idx * IMAGE_SIZE + IMAGE_SIZE);
      batchImagesArray.set(image, i * IMAGE_SIZE);

      const label =
          data[1].slice(idx * NUM_CLASSES, idx * NUM_CLASSES + NUM_CLASSES);
      batchLabelsArray.set(label, i * NUM_CLASSES);
    }

    const xs = tf.tensor2d(batchImagesArray, [batchSize, IMAGE_SIZE]);
    const labels = tf.tensor2d(batchLabelsArray, [batchSize, NUM_CLASSES]);

    return {xs, labels};
  }
}
```

The implementation JS file

```
import {FMnistData} from './fashion-data.js';
var canvas, ctx, saveButton, clearButton;
var pos = {x:0, y:0};
var rawImage;
var model;

function getModel() {

    model = tf.sequential();

    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({inputShape: [28, 28, 1], kernelSize: 3, filters: 8, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: [2, 2]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.conv2d({filters: 16, kernelSize: 3, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.maxPooling2d({poolSize: [2, 2]}));
    model.add(tf.layers.flatten());
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 128, activation: 'relu'}));
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'softmax'}));

    model.compile({optimizer: tf.train.adam(), loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy']});

    return model;
}

async function train(model, data) {
    const metrics = ['loss', 'val_loss', 'acc', 'val_acc'];
    const container =  { name: 'Model Training', styles: { height: '1000px' } };
    const fitCallbacks = tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(container, metrics);

    const BATCH_SIZE = 512;
    const TRAIN_DATA_SIZE = 6000;
    const TEST_DATA_SIZE = 1000;

    const [trainXs, trainYs] = tf.tidy(() => {
        const d = data.nextTrainBatch(TRAIN_DATA_SIZE);
        return [
            d.xs.reshape([TRAIN_DATA_SIZE, 28, 28, 1]),
            d.labels
        ];
    });

    const [testXs, testYs] = tf.tidy(() => {
        const d = data.nextTestBatch(TEST_DATA_SIZE);
        return [
            d.xs.reshape([TEST_DATA_SIZE, 28, 28, 1]),
            d.labels
        ];
    });

    return model.fit(trainXs, trainYs, {
        batchSize: BATCH_SIZE,
        validationData: [testXs, testYs],
        epochs: 10,
        shuffle: true,
        callbacks: fitCallbacks
    });
}

function setPosition(e){
    pos.x = e.clientX-100;
    pos.y = e.clientY-100;
}

function draw(e) {
    if(e.buttons!=1) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 24;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    rawImage.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}

function erase() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,280,280);
}

function save() {
    var raw = tf.browser.fromPixels(rawImage,1);
    var resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(raw, [28,28]);
    var tensor = resized.expandDims(0);

    var prediction = model.predict(tensor);
    var pIndex = tf.argMax(prediction, 1).dataSync();

    var classNames = ["T-shirt/top", "Trouser", "Pullover",
                      "Dress", "Coat", "Sandal", "Shirt",
                      "Sneaker",  "Bag", "Ankle boot"];


    alert(classNames[pIndex]);
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    rawImage = document.getElementById('canvasimg');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,280,280);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", setPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseenter", setPosition);
    saveButton = document.getElementById('sb');
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", save);
    clearButton = document.getElementById('cb');
    clearButton.addEventListener("click", erase);
}


async function run() {
    const data = new FMnistData();
    await data.load();
    const model = getModel();
    tfvis.show.modelSummary({name: 'Model Architecture'}, model);
    await train(model, data);
    await model.save('downloads://my_model');
    init();
    alert("Training is done, try classifying your drawings!");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run);
```

I used the same version of Chrome and the Chrome server extension to run the code. What could possibly be the problem? Note: I have also checked the console logs and receive no errors there too.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code no initialization of the kernel weights, so depending on the default implementation on different machines, you might have the weight initialized to 0, which makes it very difficult for the optimizer to initiate its convergence.

Try in the implementation JS file section, in the `get_model` function, in the layers definition, to add an option `kernelInitializer: 'glorotUniform'` to see if any improvement.

Comment: I had earlier though about this too, but you cannot expect so drastic changes just due to bad initialization of weights, 0.81 and an unchanging 0.2 is far